# Getting ZFS per dataset IO statistics (or NFS per export IO statistics)

Tags: solaris, nfs, zfs, opensolaris, openindiana

Where do I find statistics about how IO is divided between zfs datasets? (zpool iostat only tells me how much IO a pool is experiencing.)

All the relevant datasets are used through NFS, so I'd be happy with per export NFS IO statistics also.

We're currently running OpenIndiana

[edit]

It seems that operation and byte counter are available in kstat

```
kstat -p unix:*:vopstats_???????
...
unix:0:vopstats_2d90002:nputpage        50
unix:0:vopstats_2d90002:nread   12390785
...
unix:0:vopstats_2d90002:read_bytes      22272845340
unix:0:vopstats_2d90002:readdir_bytes   477996168
...
```

...but the strange hexadecimal ID numbers have to be resolved from `/etc/mnttab` (better ideas?)

```
rpool/export/home/jkj /export/home/jkj zfs rw,...,dev=2d90002 1308471917
```

Now writing a munin plugin to use the data...

Comment: Maybe with some dtrace spells? Also looked a bit in kstat, but didn't find anything per dataset.

Comment: From what I know, this information is available in the Fishworks interface for any Oracle ZFS appliances using DTRACE. So, the information is definitely there, somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this... In this instance I have a ZFS filesystem '/volumes/lab3_pool_a/data02/alpha/' and I am using fsstat to get some basic statistics about it. Notice, I am getting stats for both, ZFS as a whole, and this one filesystem. By the way, fsstat has some good options and may give you just what you need.

```
# fsstat zfs /volumes/lab3_pool_a/data02/alpha/ 1

 new  name   name  attr  attr lookup rddir  read read  write write
 file remov  chng   get   set    ops   ops   ops bytes   ops bytes
    0     0     0    27     0     27     0     0     0     1   208 zfs
    0     0     0     0     0      0     0     0     0     0     0 /volumes/lab3_pool_a/data02/alpha
```

Comment: I've done something similar to this, but remember that fsstat operates at the VFS layer, so not all the IO you see here is actually going to/from your zpool.  The VFS stats will include IO that is served from RAM cache as well.  Additionally, ZFS reorders and coalesces quite a bit of IO, so when you compare fsstat to 'zpool iostat' you often see very different numbers.

Comment: Yep, these are somewhat sanitized stats, but they may still be suitable, depending upon what the real need is for this data.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to slashdot's comments above: this one-liner does the same thing over all ZFS datasets (as determined by the pattern of the device column in mount(1M) output:

```
fsstat -i `mount | awk '{if($3 ~ /^[^\/:]+\//) {print $1;}}'` 1
```